# dash not expanding glob wildcards in chroot

Tags: debian, wildcards, raspbian, dash

I'm working with a copy of Raspbian, installed with [pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen). Pi-gen runs in a Docker container with a volume for the filesystem, running `debootstrap` and custom scripts inside a `chroot` to the volume.

I'm running a shell inside the Raspbian filesystem using `chroot` and `qemu-arm-static`, but without Docker.

I noticed that the `mkinitramfs` script was not working. I traced the problem back to `dash`, which the script is running in.

For some reason `dash` is not expanding filename wildcards in commands:

```
# echo /*
/*
# ls /
bin boot dev etc home lib media mnt opt proc root run sbin sys tmp usr var
```

This happens in all folders inside the chroot and *also in scripts*. 
This breaks a lot of stuff.

However, wildcard expansion works normally in filesystems bind-mounted inside the `chroot`, such as `/proc` and `/run`. Also, path expansion using the same `dash` binary works inside a different `chroot`.

I've already tried `set +f` and `set +o noglob` with no luck. The `noglob` option is definitely not on:

```
# set -o
Current option settings
errexit         off
noglob          off
ignoreeof       off
interactive     on
monitor         on
noexec          off
stdin           on
xtrace          off
verbose         off
vi              off
emacs           off
noclobber       off
allexport       off
notify          off
nounset         off
nolog           off
debug           off
```

I'm running version `0.5.8-2.4` of the `dash` package from `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf`. The host machine is running Kali Linux 2019.1 with kernel `4.19.0-kali4-amd64`.

Has anyone seen a similar problem before? What could I use as a workaround?

**Update:** The following is the relevant part of the `strace` dump in a working `chroot`:

```
read(0, "echo /*\n", 8192)              = 8
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 11 entries */, 32768)    = 264
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "/bin /dev /etc /lib /pls /proc /"..., 46) = 46
```

The same in the non-working `chroot`:

```
read(0, "echo /*\n", 8192)              = 8
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 20 entries */, 32768)  = 488
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "/*\n", 3)                     = 3
```

Comment: After failing to expand `/*` when used with `echo`, have you verified with `ls /` that there are in fact visible names there?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes. Regardless of folder, expansion fails and `ls` sees the files. Also happens in scripts.

Comment: does `case /foo in /*) echo yes;; /foo) echo no; esac` print `yes` or `no`? `dash` is not using the system's `glob(3)` function by default, but is using the systems `fnmatch(3)` for both glob expansion and `case` pattern matching.

Comment: @mosvy It prints `yes`, as expected.

Comment: If you have `strace`, you can try comparing the output of `strace -ve trace=getdents,getdents64 >/dev/null dash -c 'echo /*'` with that of `... ls /`.

Comment: @mosvy Here's the result of both commands in both chroots. https://pastebin.com/ZqiTiQJY (The chroots obviously have different contents.)

Comment: @PurkkaKoodari have you ever found the reason? It started happening to me, even though it was working before on the same machine.

Comment: @Étienne Nope. Haven't been working on the project for a while. If you have a simpler environment that can reproduce the problem, please let me know. I suspect it is some corner case in the code for `dash` or `libc`, especially if it changes with an update.

Comment: I have a very similar environnement. I am running debootstrap inside an amd64 docker container, and the debootstrap creates an i386 platform, thus it does chroot into a i386 sysroot. This is running on a gitlab server and was working until last week (so probably something was updated, a commit which was compiling before is now failing, built with the same docker container).

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360617/how-to-debug-a-broken-wildcard-expansion

Comment: Please edit question to show output of `ls -la /`.

Comment: The `strace` output is irrelevant. `echo` does not expand the glob, bash does.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I don't have access to the environment in question anymore, but I know it should essentially look like a normal root directory. It's created by debootstrap and chrooted into. (Debootstrap is meant to create a regular Debian installation into a folder.) The only difference is that the system architecture used inside the chroot is different than the one outside.

Comment: Regarding the strace output, that's an excerpt of `strace dash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

As [Étienne found out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582245/360809) (please, upvote them for the research effort), the root cause seems to be a change in glibc 2.28.

- `getdents64` on 64-bit Linux can return `d_off` values that don't fit in a 32-bit `int`. On 32-bit systems it only returns 32-bit values.
- `qemu-user` that emulates a 32-bit system on 64-bit Linux just passes the syscall through, so a 32-bit userland process can get overflowing values.
- glibc 2.28 has a [change](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/12/27/155) that makes `readdir` always use `getdents64` and error out if `d_off` doesn't fit. On real 32-bit systems, this must not be causing problems because glibc went through with it. (Previously it called `getdents` on 32-bit systems, this returns 32-bit values and the kernel does any truncating.)

### Fix (or the lack thereof)

[This glibc bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23960) is currently tracking progress on this issue. It'll take its time to be fixed and eventually deployed to your distribution.

### Workarounds

- The simplest workaround I can see is running these builds on a system with a 32-bit Linux kernel.
- If you can downgrade the glibc version (in the chroot!) to 2.27 that would fix the problem, but that might cause dependency problems and will alter the image you're building.
- One can also apply one of the many patches in the linked threads, but that will require compiling (and probably detaching from your package manager) either your kernel, glibc or (probably the easiest) QEMU.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same symptoms on my machine, even though I am working on a different project (based on docker, not on QEMU), so I cannot prove that it is the issue in your case, but it probably is.

I have a build which is sometimes working, and sometimes failing, because the wildcard does not always get expanded (I am doing `ls /tmp/linux*deb`).

Strace shows that for the failing case, a call to getdents is returning `-1 EOVERFLOW (Value too large for defined data type)`

Working case:

```
[pid 29791] open("/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 29791] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid 29791] getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768) = 60
[pid 29791] getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
[pid 29791] close(3)                    = 0
```

Failing case:

```
[pid 25606] open("/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 25606] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=100, ...}) = 0
[pid 25606] getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768) = 16
[pid 25606] getdents(3, 0x585a831c, 32768) = -1 EOVERFLOW (Value too large for defined data type)
[pid 25606] close(3)                    = 0
```

I found a couple of bug-reports referencing the issue (getdents returns a 64 bits value, but the caller expects a 32 bits value in this case):

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39732
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1805913
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205957

Comment: Thanks for doing the research! I'll self-answer with what I can gather from those links, have an upvote in the meantime.